# Setting up task scheduler in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4, xampp

I am trying to develop an app in `Laravel 4.2` framework. For this purpose, I tried to set up `task scheduler`.

I have created commands for scheduling and it works well.
In `Laravel` documentation, they mentioned that we need to add `Cron entry` to server:

`* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`.

I don't know where to add this  command. Can anyone help? I am using `xampp` in `windows os`

Comment: You can't schedule cron task on Windows. Only on Unix based OS

Comment: @naneri: Can you please tell that, how will I schedule tasks in windows for laravel projects?

Answer (score 0):

In `Windows` this is called `Task Scheduler`.
Just make sure you use full paths to `php.exe` and `artisan` as well.